# Не могу вывести рисунок вместо кнопки

Tags: java

Хочу сделать кнопку-рисунок.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;


public class ButonsMenu extends Canvas implements MouseListener{

    public void paint(Graphics some) {

        Image buttinDelete = new ImageIcon("Image/TestButtonImage.GIF").getImage();
        Image newimg = buttinDelete.getScaledInstance( 150, 30,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH );
        some.drawImage(newimg,0,0,this);

    }
    @Override

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

}
```

при обращении видит пустую область (открываю во фрейме).

Что я упустил?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена банально, неверный адрес. Измененные места работающего кода:

```
Image buttinDelete = new ImageIcon("srs/Image/TestButtonImage.GIF").getImage();
Image newimg = buttinDelete.getScaledInstance( 150, 30,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH );
some.drawImage(newimg,0,0,null);
```